# Is it possible to run an applescript whenever Safari opens a new tab?

Tags: applescript

My router blocks certain websites and when it does, a new tab opens with the name "error" and the page says the site has been blocked.
I can close the tab by

```
tell application "Safari"
   close (tabs of window 1 whose name = "error")
end tell
```

Can this script be ran when the new tab is created?

Comment: Probably not, but you could put it in a loop that runs every second or two and leave it running, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark

This will have to do until I find a more elegant way.

```
on idle
      tell application "Safari"
         close (tabs of window 1 whose name = "error")
      end tell 
    return 10
end idle
```